# Merging multiple columns with different column names in R and transposing data

Tags: r

This is my first time posting on here and I am new to R, so hopefully I am asking my question correctly.  I am trying to create a new variable (`Name` and `Day`) in my `dataset`based on two other variables.  My data looks like this:

```
ID  Name    Day
1   Abbey   06-Jan-2009
2   Abbey   07-Jan-2009
3   Abbey   06-Jan-2009
4   Abbey   07-Jan-2009
5   Fred    09-Jan-2009
6   Fred    10-Jan-2009
7   Fred    09-Jan-2009
8   Fred    10-Jan-2009
```

And I want the new variable to look like this:

```
ID  Name    Day           Time
1   Abbey   06-Jan-2009   1
2   Abbey   07-Jan-2009   2
3   Abbey   06-Jan-2009   1
4   Abbey   07-Jan-2009   2
5   Fred    09-Jan-2009   1
6   Fred    10-Jan-2009   2
7   Fred    09-Jan-2009   1
8   Fred    10-Jan-2009   2
```

I have tried:

```
dataset$Time<-as.numeric (as.factor(dataset$Name),(as.factor(dataset$Day)))
```

However, this doesn't restart the Time at 1 for each variable.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: If one of the answers below addresses your question, please consider checking it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
transform(dataset, Time=c(ave(as.character(Day), Name, FUN=factor)))
```

You may or may not need the `as.character` depending on whether your data starts of as character or factor.  Note we use `c` to drop factor attributes.

Answer (score 2):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)#data.table_1.9.5
setDT(df1)[, id:=frank(Day, ties.method='dense'),.(Name)][]
#   ID  Name         Day id
#1:  1 Abbey 06-Jan-2009  1
#2:  2 Abbey 07-Jan-2009  2
#3:  3 Abbey 06-Jan-2009  1
#4:  4 Abbey 07-Jan-2009  2
#5:  5  Fred 09-Jan-2009  1
#6:  6  Fred 10-Jan-2009  2
#7:  7  Fred 09-Jan-2009  1
#8:  8  Fred 10-Jan-2009  2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be fairly easy with the `dplyr` package

```
dd<-data.frame(
    ID=1:8,
    Name=c("Abbey", "Abbey", "Abbey", "Abbey", "Fred", "Fred", "Fred", "Fred"),
    Day=c("06-Jan-2009", "07-Jan-2009", "06-Jan-2009", "07-Jan-2009", "09-Jan-2009", "10-Jan-2009", "09-Jan-2009", "10-Jan-2009")
)

library(dplyr)
dd %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(id=as.numeric(factor(Day)))

#   ID  Name         Day id
# 1  1 Abbey 06-Jan-2009  1
# 2  2 Abbey 07-Jan-2009  2
# 3  3 Abbey 06-Jan-2009  1
# 4  4 Abbey 07-Jan-2009  2
# 5  5  Fred 09-Jan-2009  1
# 6  6  Fred 10-Jan-2009  2
# 7  7  Fred 09-Jan-2009  1
# 8  8  Fred 10-Jan-2009  2
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to MrFlick.  Be careful about dates -- they can either be in date or character formats...

```
# Uncomment if dplyr not installed
# install.packages(dplyr)
library(dplyr)
ID <- 1:8
Name <- rep(c("Abbey", "Fred"), times=c(4,4))
Day <- c("06-Jan-2009", "07-Jan-2009","06-Jan-2009", "07-Jan-2009",
         "09-Jan-2009", "10-Jan-2009","09-Jan-2009", "10-Jan-2009")

dataset <- data.frame(ID, Name, Day)

dataset <- 
  group_by(dataset, Name) %>%
  mutate(Time = as.numeric(as.factor((as.Date(Day, "%d-%b-%Y")))))
```